# How to play videos from android internal storage

Tags: android, gridview, video, android-intent

I am able to create videos in android internal storage(/data/data/com.exx.appname/app_Album/Videos/1394607432167.3gp) and i am showing it in a gridview. On griditem click i want to play the video. All is fine on external storage but on internal storage if i click the videos in gridview i am getting an alert "Can't play this video".My code for playing videos is

```
    String videoFilePath = videopath.get(v.getId());
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    File newFile = new File(videoFilePath);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile),"video/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

I searched it  and tried using Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE for the folder creation but nothing is working for me.Plz guide me.Thanks in advance